# The google sheet is not responsive on an Android cell phone

Tags: android, google-sheets, google-apps-script, responsive

I've created a simple form on a google sheet . With the authorizations I have given on the PC the data are transferred from one page to another page on the same sheet with the help of a button by assigning a dataSubmit method. In fact it works well without any error. However, despite having the same permissions, the button does not submit the data on the same sheet on an Android-based phone. The page does not seem to be responsive. How can I solve this problem? Kind regards

NOte:i've used appscripts, no third party application.

Kind Regards,

Gokhan

I've checked the authorization levels and the relevant person can update the page. He's full authorized to change, write and update this page. The appsscript is assigned to the button.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to click buttons on Android devices. The way I do it is with a tickbox or dropdown that, with the help of onEdit(e), triggers your suggested action

[image]

For example, it could look like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getA1Notation() == "B1" && e.value == true) {dataSubmit()}
}
```

OR

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getA1Notation() == "C1" && e.value == "Submit"){dataSubmit()}
}
```

And include some logic that also clears that value so you can use it again for the next submission