# Allow google script to use private sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have two google sheets files a private and a public one.

The public any can access. It has a script that pull and pushes data to the private file.

However, I would like to keep the private one well private, however, in order for users to push and pull data from the private file, they need editor access to the private file.

How can I work around this issue, whilst keeping the private file locked except for the script?

Comment: Although @[`Martín`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20363318) is correct, a script-free option for this is by using [`IMPORTRANGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340) to `push and pull data` from the spreadsheets. Since you have access to both files, you can set the formula on the public spreadsheet to point to the private one, or vice versa, and get the data that you need. The output is dynamic, so whatever changes are made by an `Editor` on any of the spreadsheets will be reflected on the other.

Answer (score 1):

The way round you could analyze is to create an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable). This way, the script is going to be run as if it were by you; and it would have all the permissions that you have.

If the code is run onEdit, you should change the name of the function to other thing (whenEdited(e) for example) and create an installable trigger like this one:

[image]

If it's run by a button or menu, you should consider creating, for example, a checkbox or dropdown that allows you to manage it like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77901739/the-google-sheet-is-not-responsive-on-an-android-cell-phone/77902000#77902000)